# Update Documents From Each Value of an Input Array

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I have a JSON with two keys: id and name. I need a way to insert that id on my collection (querys.project.name) when the name on it and on the JSON matches.

Example of my JSON:

```
var projectsMysql = [
{
    "id" : 1,
    "name" : "Something"
},
{
    "id" : 5,
    "name" : "Something else"
},
{
    "id" : 50,
    "name" : "Some name"
}]
```

and in my collection about 60 documents like this one:

```
  {
  "_id" : ObjectId("58e42bf30a34d641be6c25c2"),
  "folio" : "R-666-69",
  "alias_purchase" : "Deal",
  "project" : {
      "description" : "",
      "name" : "Something else"
      // "projectsMysql_id" : 5 THIS SHOULD BE PLACED HERE
  },
}
```

I wrote a function for Node.js but now I need to run this directly on the mongo shell, I read that I need to use cursor.forEach() method but I couldn't find a way to do it, this is my function:

```
projectsMysql
.forEach(function(project){
var query = {
  name: project.name
}
db.getCollection('requests')
  .find(query)
  .exec(function(err, response){
    if (err) {
      return 
    }
    if (response) {
      db.getCollection('requests')
        .update({id: response.id}, {$set: {
          'project.projectsMysql_id': project.id
           console.log("element inserted"); 
        }})
        .exec(function(err){
        });
    }
  });
});
```

Can you point me in to the right direction?

Comment: db.requests.find().forEach( function(myDoc) { console.log("somestuff") } );
maybe you can try making your sql queries in the JS function based on `myDoc.name`

Comment: But I need to iterate all the names in my collection and compare them with all the names on the JSON, until I found a match so I can insert the id that belongs to that project name.

Comment: Are you running in the "mongo shell"? There is no such method `exec()` in the "mongo shell". So are you actually asking for "mongoose" or are you just copying code from somewhere else without realizing what it is for? Are you "certain" that the `name` is indeed "unique"? Or do you not care if it matches in multiple documents and updates ALL of those where it matches?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I need to run it on mongo shell but my code was for Node.js.  Names are unique in the JSON and yes, I need to update ALL documents that match.

Answer (score 0):

What you want here is [`bulkWrite()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/), where instead of actually executing an `update()` for each document within the `projectsMysql` array you actually just construct a "single" statement made of "multiple" updates which sends to the server and updates the appropriate documents:

```
db.getCollection('requests').bulkWrite(
  projectsMysql.map(({ id, name }) => 
    ({ "updateOne": {
      "filter": { "project.name": name },
      "update": { "$set": { "project.id": id } }
    }})
  )
)
```

If you expect "multiple documents" to match the condition, then simply switch to `updateMany`:

```
db.getCollection('requests').bulkWrite(
  projectsMysql.map(({ id, name }) => 
    ({ "updateMany": {
      "filter": { "project.name": name },
      "update": { "$set": { "project.id": id } }
    }})
  )
)
```

Your array is already in memory so there is not really any point to doing any other kind of "iteration" and you can simply [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the properties onto the `updateOne` statements ( or `updateMany` ) and issue them all in one statement. Updates are only actually processed where there is a "match" and indeed where there is something to actually update, as existing values will be left alone using [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/).

---

To Demonstrate, considering these documents:

```
{
  "folio" : "R-666-69",
  "alias_purchase" : "Deal",
  "project" : {
      "description" : "",
      "name" : "Something else"
  }
},
{
  "folio" : "R-666-67",
  "alias_purchase" : "Deal",
  "project" : {
      "description" : "",
      "name" : "Some name"
  }
},
{
  "folio" : "R-666-68",
  "alias_purchase" : "Deal",
  "project" : {
      "description" : "",
      "name" : "Some name"
  }
}
{
  "folio" : "R-666-64",
  "alias_purchase" : "Deal",
  "project" : {
      "description" : "",
      "name" : "Something"
  }
},
{
  "folio" : "R-666-65",
  "alias_purchase" : "Deal",
  "project" : {
      "description" : "",
      "name" : "Different"
  }
}
```

The the following update:

```
var projectsMysql = [
{
    "id" : 1,
    "name" : "Something"
},
{
    "id" : 5,
    "name" : "Something else"
},
{
    "id" : 50,
    "name" : "Some name"
}]

db.getCollection('requests').bulkWrite(
  projectsMysql.map(({ id, name }) => 
    ({ "updateMany": {
      "filter": { "project.name": name },
      "update": { "$set": { "project.id": id } }
    }})
  )
)
```

Returns the response:

```
{
        "acknowledged" : true,
        "deletedCount" : 0,
        "insertedCount" : 0,
        "matchedCount" : 4,
        "upsertedCount" : 0,
        "insertedIds" : {

        },
        "upsertedIds" : {

        }
}
```

And alters the matched documents accordingly:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b206a48f7fa0c655d90157a"),
        "folio" : "R-666-69",
        "alias_purchase" : "Deal",
        "project" : {
                "description" : "",
                "name" : "Something else",
                "id" : 5
        }
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b206a48f7fa0c655d90157b"),
        "folio" : "R-666-67",
        "alias_purchase" : "Deal",
        "project" : {
                "description" : "",
                "name" : "Some name",
                "id" : 50
        }
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b206a48f7fa0c655d90157c"),
        "folio" : "R-666-68",
        "alias_purchase" : "Deal",
        "project" : {
                "description" : "",
                "name" : "Some name",
                "id" : 50
        }
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b206a48f7fa0c655d90157d"),
        "folio" : "R-666-64",
        "alias_purchase" : "Deal",
        "project" : {
                "description" : "",
                "name" : "Something",
                "id" : 1
        }
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b206a48f7fa0c655d90157e"),
        "folio" : "R-666-65",
        "alias_purchase" : "Deal",
        "project" : {
                "description" : "",
                "name" : "Different"
        }
}
```

Comment: That's a really nice approach thanks, although I'm getting
Error: Line 189: Unexpected token ) 
that's the line number six of your code, I'm using mongo v3.4.15, do you think that's the problem?

Comment: @NullEins Missing a "brace"` `}`. My fault for just typing in here directly.

Comment: @NullEins It updates the document in your question just fine. As I stated in the answer, it will "match" and show in the result only documents which actually match the conditions you have. You see "modifed" in the result for only actual modifications which are present. Therefore if there is already a `"project.id"` with the value to be set, then there is no recorded modification. If you are running against other data than "in your question" then you should not be, since that is not the question you asked. If there is nothing showing in "matched" then the `name` values are not the same